# force iframe or disable javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a situation where I have to load a page in a frame. This page is not mine, so I cannot edit its code. I want it to load inside the iframe, but it overtakes the browser tab. When I took a look at the source, i found a function that does:

```
top.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Is there a way I can block a call to just this function, or if I somehow I can force this page to stay inside the frame.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: They put it there for a reason. Ask them to remove it since that is what thy would want you to do in the first place for copyright reasons.

Comment: If they do not want it to be framed, they put the code there. It is like parking in a no parking spot and removing the sign. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364721/force-iframe-or-disable-javascript

Comment: Well, copyright and legal issues asside, I atleast would like to know if it can be done at all! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your main file put

```
top = new Object();
top.location = new Object();
top.location.href = function(){
  alert('its calling me');
}
```

Comment: I think you'd have to overwrite `top`. Using `var top` does not work in Chrome; `top` keeps its original value. Edit: overwriting `top` does not work either in Chrome, perhaps for security reasons.

Comment: But a valid way of thinking :) replacing document.write for example for annoying ads, does work.

Comment: can you try to override just property like top.location = new Object()

Comment: even if I put that in the main file, shouldn't it affect the loading of main file itself?